# Ramsey number, enumerating graphs.

Tags: combinatorics, ramsey-theory

"Let G be a complete graph on 25 vertices and let the edges of G be colored either brown or green. If there is no green triangle, what is the largest complete brown sub-graph you can be sure G has?"

After some tedious pencil work I ended up with the answer that the largest brown clique in G has 7 vertices, is there any way to prove (or disprove) this by counting instead of drawing?

Thanks

Comment: $7$ is the correct answer according to the table of small Ramsey numbers given [here](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/DS1).

Comment: Thanks, but.. If I did not have a table, can I somehow verify that 7 is the answer?

Comment: Since $R(m,n) \leq R(m-1,n)+R(m,n-1)$, and what you ask is to show that $R(7,3) \leq 25$, it is sufficent to prove that $R(6,3) \leq 18$ and $R(7,2) \leq 7$. The latter is trivial, so you can reduce the problem to showing that  in a complete graph of 18 vertices with no green triangle, there must be a brown clique of size 6.